# C# detect if line in file has string

Tags: c#

i have a problem. I have a text file and want to get the output of the line in a console window.

My file looks like this

```
parameter1=Test1
parameter2=12345
parameter3=Dir1
```

I want to read the lines and the output should be only

```
Test1
12345
Dir1
```

The string parameter1-3 is variable and could be edited in the text file. It could be lees or more.
The text file could have

```
read from file:
parameter1=Test1
parameter2=12345
parameter3=Dir1
parameter4=Hi
```

```
Test1
12345
Dir
Hi
```

or

```
read from file:
parameter1=Test1
parameter2=12345
```

```
Test1
12345
```

I need an idea how i can solve the problem. Thanks for help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow  Please see: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/4800344) and I recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You're looking for key/value pairs, not check for a string in a line. There are several questions about this. A quick & dirty way is to split by space then `=` and only keep the second value in each pair. Or you can use a regular expression that captures text around `=` and keep the second part of each match

Comment: If the pairs are in separate lines you only need a single split, if not just find `=` and take everything after it.

Comment: @poohnoob, I've updated my answer to check if the parameters have the structure you want. Please check. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77103551/5935112

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@"^parameter\d+=.*");

        var allLines  = File.ReadLines("YOUR FILE PATH HERE");

        var values = allLines
            // The line below filters out the items that don't start with "parameter". Comment it if you want anything to be accepted.
            .Where(item => regex.IsMatch(item))
            .Select(item => item.Substring(item.IndexOf('=')+1))
            .ToList();

        foreach (var item in values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: `ReadLines` instead of `ReadAllLines` doesn't read the entire file to memory which is not required since `Select` wants just an enumeration.

Comment: Side note: I'd rather use `Skip(1)` instead of `LastOrDefault`: when facing `a=b=c` I can believe in `b=c` parameter *value*, but not in `a=b` parameter *name*.

Comment: Looks OK now, the last side note is that `.*` is *redundant* in the regular expression, `^parameter[0-9]+=` will be enough (I changed `\d` into `[0-9]` to avoid an academical problem with digits - `\d` matches any Unicode digit, including Persian, Indian ones etc.).  My +1